# golang exec.Command in different folder

Tags: go

I have a problem with exec.Command with .Dir assigned. When I run command from the app I get an error. but if I run it from the shell the same command is working fine.

```
command := exec.Command("git", "rev-parse", "--verify", "tags/v1.0.0^{commit}")
command.Dir = "sub/subdir"
out, err := command.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Printf("Executed command [%s] %s\nErrorCode = %s\nOutput = %s\n", command.Dir, command.Args, err, out)
```

The output:

```
Executed command [sub/subdir] [git rev-parse --verify tags/v1.0.0^{commit}]
ErrorCode = exit status 128 
Output = fatal: Needed a single revision
```

Shell command:

```
$ (cd sub/subdir; git rev-parse --verify tags/v1.0.0^{commit})
c1f3b8707ac001dab875781def3c729e3ed6de2c
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path. Check out [filepath.Abs](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Abs)

Comment: Or better yet, try using [`filepath.Abs`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to build the absolute path. Print that value to make sure you're using the path you expect.

Comment: It didn't help - same result.